# Add multiple columns based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add multiple new columns based on a condition but when I run the code for making a new column, the last new column made from the conditions is replaced.

```
new_df <- df %>% mutate(dat1_dat2_new = case_when(
  dat1 == 0 & dat2 == 0 ~ 'TW',
  dat1 == 0 & dat2 == 1 ~ 'FS', 
  dat1 == 1 & dat2 == 0 ~ 'FW',
  dat1 == 1 & dat2 == 1 ~ 'TS'))
new_df$dat1_dat2_new
```

but when I run

```
new_df <- df %>% mutate(dat3_dat4_new = case_when(
      dat3 == 0 & dat4 == 0 ~ 'TW',
      dat3 == 0 & dat4 == 1 ~ 'FS', 
      dat3 == 1 & dat4 == 0 ~ 'FW',
      dat3 == 1 & dat4 == 1 ~ 'TS'))
    new_df$dat3_dat4_new
```

it replaces new_df$dat1_dat2_new

Comment: You need `new_df <- new_df %>% rest of the code` in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code, you are replacing the original `new_df` with the new `new_df`. You never actually added a new column after `dat1_dat2_new`. You need - `new_df <- new_df %>% rest of the code` in the second case.

Also, a simpler way would be to create both new columns in a single `mutate` -

```
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    dat1_dat2_new = case_when(
      dat1 == 0 & dat2 == 0 ~ 'TW',
      dat1 == 0 & dat2 == 1 ~ 'FS', 
      dat1 == 1 & dat2 == 0 ~ 'FW',
      dat1 == 1 & dat2 == 1 ~ 'TS'
    ),
    dat3_dat4_new = case_when(
      dat3 == 0 & dat4 == 0 ~ 'TW',
      dat3 == 0 & dat4 == 1 ~ 'FS', 
      dat3 == 1 & dat4 == 0 ~ 'FW',
      dat3 == 1 & dat4 == 1 ~ 'TS'
    )
  )
```